# how to open the iTunes review URL controller not the tap page?

Tags: ios, iphone

Does anybody knows how to open the "write a review" controller like this:
i am sorry i have no enough reputation to post images,the controller pop up after user click the "Write a Review" button in "Reviews" tag page.

I know how to open the "review" tag page use this url:

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=APP_ID&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software
```

but i also want to open the "review" controller use URL,can this possible? thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about App store review tab ?

Comment: @DipenChudasama not the review tag, it is the controller after user click the "Write a Review" button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to directly start the review creation process. The user will have to tap 'Write a Review'.

Comment: i think you are right, i can not find something about this issue

Answer (score 1):

It is possible..

You have to use below URL for that.

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=YOURAPPID
```

Don't forget to add you appID in last 'Replace "**YOURAPPID**" with your real app ID' this will working :)

Comment: This will open the reviews page and is the same URL which the thread starter already posted. He wants to directly open the screen where the user can actually enter a review message & select the stars instead.

Comment: thank you for your answer , not the "reviews" tag , i said the controller after user click the "Write a Review" button in "Reviews" tag page